# CSS JS date formatting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, date, format

I have an unusual date formatting issue that, perhaps, someone else has encountered.

I have an MVC application with textboxes with `@class = datepicker`.
I have a global formatting string (`dd-MMM-yyyy`)
There's a bit of JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

Issue: When I click on the textbox and select a date, I get something like the following:

```
01-JanuaryJan-2017
```

I assumed that, maybe, i had some formatting somewhere like `dd-MMMMMMM-YYYY`, but I do not.  I'm at a loss.

I've inherited this application and am not extremely well-versed in web development, but this seems like an issue that I should be able to figure out.

I realize i don't have a lot of details here, but I'm also only looking for generic/high-level solutions like:
Check in this general area, or look for this, etc.

Comment: format is not the correct property name for the options object. Try `dateFormat` - docs here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: One thing that date parsers and formatters seem determined not to agree on is the tokens to use for parsing and formatting. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong format. Use the right one from the following (as you wish):

```
format: 'dd-MM-yy'
```

which will display the date like this `03-January-2017`

OR

```
format: 'dd-M-yy'
```

which will display the date like this `03-Jan-2017`

Comment: that would be `'dd-M-yy'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the (incomplete) list of valid values for the `dateFormat` property from the [jQueryUI DatePicker Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/datepicker/):

> The format can be combinations of the following:
>
> - d - day of month (no leading zero)
> - dd - day of month (two digit)
> - o - day of the year (no leading zeros)
> - oo - day of the year (three digit)
> - D - day name short
> - DD - day name long
> - m - month of year (no leading zero)
> - mm - month of year (two digit)
> - M - month name short
> - MM - month name long
> - y - year (two digit)
> - yy - year (four digit)
> - @ - Unix timestamp (ms since 01/01/1970)
> - ! - Windows ticks (100ns since 01/01/0001)
> - '...' - literal text
> - '' - single quote
> - anything else - literal text

So, in your case, you are combining `MM`, which is the full month name with `M` which is the short month name, resulting in `JanuaryJan`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply!

It seems that I was confused due to the different formatting options between jQuery and C#.

i was unable to get dateFormat to work.

This worked for me:
format: 'dd-M-yyyy';

I tried 'yy', but I only got the last two digits.

Thanks all :).

Comment: Interesting about the property name.. I'll have to look more into it. Glad the list of values helped, though! I will update my post

Comment: I read somewhere else that dateFormat requires a plugin that must explicitly be called in <script>?  not sure, either way, thanks for the info.